# Each player throws two dice

Tags: probability

probability problem:

players a and b throws two dice and
a player wins if the sum for the first throw is 11 or 7 and Each player loses at once if it is 3, 2. For other 
case,throw two dice is repeated.the probability that player a wins at the $k$th throw?

my attempt: $ p(\text{a win at the $k$th throw})= ( \frac{25}{36} )^{k-1}(\frac{8}{36})$

can someone help me?

thanks.

Comment: How did you come up with that answer?

Comment: ...Especially in view of the fact that 25+8 is not 36.

Comment: @Did: Clearly $\frac{25}{36}$ is the probability of getting a non-decisive roll.

Comment: Does player b have any relevance to the problem at all? As you’ve stated it, it appears that they’re not actually playing against each other, but merely against the dice, so to speak. And if b really is irrelevant, your analysis looks fine to me: you’ve given the probability of $k-1$ non-decisive rolls followed by a winning roll.

Comment: I edited answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes of course, and this remark was meant to engage the OP in thinking about the answer they had been given. That my try succeeded is doubtful though, in view of subsequent events on the page.

Comment: @Did: I think it quite clear that the OP had *already* thought about the problem, and correctly at that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sure, you think that.

Comment: @Did: I do. Any reasonable person would.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It is quite clear because you said so and anybody disagreeing with your decree is unreasonable. A convenient worldview.

Comment: @Did: No, it’s quite clear because it’s quite clear. I have no idea what you think was going on, unless you imagine that the OP found the right answer somewhere and then for some strange reason asked about it here. Note that the OP **did** correctly identify the probabilities of the three types of roll; if you did not see this at the time, you can check the edit history. I see no principled reason to doubt that the OP is uncertain of his or her command of these ideas and simply wanted confirmation.

Comment: @jini25: I’ll take a look.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You mean, the part that was there for 17 minutes? Yes I had missed it. (By the way, the content of this transient edit is itself a bit mysterious. I guess that b (and c) there have nothing to do with player b in the question.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And THERE, what is the OP's input?

Comment: @Did: I truly have no idea what you’re on about. The OP supplied input in the original question and more input in the edit. If you don’t think that a tentative answer is input, we simply don’t speak the same language. In any case I see no profit in further discussion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was alluding to the new question of the OP (as you perfectly understood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description it appears that Player B can be completely ignored: his actions do not affect Player A’s wins and losses. If that is correct, then so is your analysis. On each roll the probability of rolling something other than $2,3,7$, or $11$ is $\frac{25}{36}$, so the probability of getting one of these non-decisive numbers $k-1$ times in a row is $\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k-1}$. On each roll the probability of getting a winning number is $\frac8{36}$, so the probability of getting $k-1$ non-decisive numbers followed by a winning number, i.e., of winning on the $k$-th roll, is indeed $\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac8{36}\right)$.